# Unity referencing a Script gives weird error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to reference a Script from another GameObject in Unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class jumpcheck : MonoBehaviour
{

    GameObject Player;
    fuckingMove fm;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    fm = Player.GetComponent<"fuckingMove">();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    Player.fm.isGrounded = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit2D() {
    Player.fm.isGrounded = false;
}
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting this error and i don't know why.

> Assets/Scripts/jumpcheck.cs(16,49): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 3):

Generics expect type as parameter not type name as string.

```cs
//Incorrect
Player.GetComponent<"ComponentName">();

//Correct
Player.GetComponent<ComponentName>();
```